# Angular Material md-button not rendering correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm pretty new to angularjs and angular material, and I was wondering why my md-button might not be showing up the way it should on my browser but worked on codepen. I put this in my html file:

```
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>
  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src='app.js'></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='MainCont'>
<md-button class='md-primary'>hello</md-button>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MainCont', function(){
});
```

The module and the controllers are all loading, but in the browser this button shows up like this:

[button picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13tcG.png)

Can someone explain to me why this might be? Thanks so much!

Comment: Well... what are you expecting??

Comment: I'm expecting the flat buttons like on the demos from angular material here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button

Comment: Then you need to add the classes that they're using, for ex: `class="md-raised md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple"`.

Comment: Even if I add "md-no-ink" like the second example, the button doesn't change to look like the one in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to import the `css` of `AngularMaterial`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
```

Comment: Oh that was a pretty dumb mistake, thanks for your help!!

Comment: Pleasure to help :)